# Catch block in Java code gets executed even when the try block satisfies the mentioned condition?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, catch-block

I am new to Java and I tried to use exceptions in my Java code to give the user an alert if in case he/she types a negative number or a non-numerical value in the text field. But still, when I enter a single-digit positive number, the catch blocks get executed.

```
    //textfield to enter the amount of Rs.
    txt_rupees = new JTextField();
    
    //KeyListener to check if the content entered in the text field is a number or not.
    txt_rupees.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            
            try {
                //convert the user input in the textfield from string to double
                double check = Double.parseDouble(txt_rupees.getText());
                
                //checking if the number entered by the user is positive or not.
                if (check > 0) {
                lb_check1.setText(" ");             
                }
                
                else {
                    lb_check1.setText("Please enter a valid number");
                }
            }       
            catch (NumberFormatException ne){
                
                //If the user enters a non-numerical character then this message should be displayed by the label.
                lb_check1.setText("ALERT: Please enter a valid float or int value in the textfield");
            }
        }           
    });
```

Comment: Your catch block only is executed when a `NumberFormatException` is thrown into de try block. It's probable than you insert the number but the parse function throw the error for any thing (maybe it's just empty on keyPressed event). Trace the `ne` error in order to determine more exactly the error

Answer (score 0):

To understand how try-catch block work, I will give an example.

```
class InsufficientMoneyException extends Exception{
    InsufficientMoneyException(int money){
        System.out.println("You only have $"+money);
    }
}

class A throws InsufficientMoneyException{
 try{
  int money = 100;
  if(money<1000) throw new InsufficientMoneyException(money);
  System.out.println("I am NOT being executed!");

 } catch (InsufficientMoneyException e){System.out.println("I am being executed!");}
}
```

Code block will get executed unless it encounters a statement that tells it to `throw a exception`. After throwing the exception, the `catch` will catch the exception and the `catch block` will get executed.

In your case,

```
                double check = Double.parseDouble(txt_rupees.getText());
```

The library function `parseDouble()` will throw the `NumberFormatException` so the lines in `try block` after this line, won't get executed.